Collection of Canonical answers (Token Questions/Lightning Rod questions)
There are some basic questions that get asked and answered again and again. Over the past year, I've gone through a bunch of tags to collect and close as duplicate many of those towards Canonical Question/Answer pairs. I'd like to collect these here, in order to have a handy list of questions to use as a "duplicate master". Also, these questions should be scrutinized over frequently, in order to update their content to maintain their quality and relevance.
Please help to maintain this list of Canonical Questions and Answers!

Obviously, most of these will eventually be featured in the frequent questions, which collects questions that get linked a lot. However, until they get listed there, this collection might help provide help finding the best "duplicate master". Also, some of this could use better canonical answers, I'll be putting up some bounties, where the need is especially obvious.

Send payment to unsynced Bitcoin Core:
I didn't receive a Bitcoin Payment. What does it mean when the Client is synchronizing?

Sync stuck at block X:
What can I do when the blockchain synchronization is stuck at a specific block?

How can I access bitcoins when my client is still synchronizing?
Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to retrieve them?

Request for general advice how to buy bitcoins:
How do you obtain bitcoins?

"I have a bunch of noob questions":
I am new to Bitcoin, how can I get started?

Zero-fee transaction not getting confirmed:
Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?

Unconfirmed transaction sent from Blockchain.info:
How to unstuck a low-fee transaction with blockchain.info?

Unconfirmed transaction sent from Electrum:
How to unstuck a low-fee transaction with Electrum?

Buying Bitcoins with PayPal:
How can I buy Bitcoin via a Credit Card or Paypal?

Getting started with mining at home:
In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?

Recovering BTC sent to a BCC address:
What would happen if you send Bitcoin (BTC) to a Bitcoin Cash (BCC) address?

Selling bitcoins: How can I sell bitcoins and transfer the funds to my bank account?

Why is there no such thing as a redirected, forged, or fake transaction?

Attacker created wallet for victim: Someone else created a wallet for me to use. Is this a scam?

User returning to bitcoin years later: I have lost my wallet, what can I do?

Advance fee scam: Is it normal to be asked for an advance fee on a withdrawal?

Recipient denies confirmed tx: Recipient has “not received” the Bitcoin I sent, but the transaction is confirmed

How does block synchronization work in Bitcoin Core today?

How do I inherit bitcoins after the death of my relative?


This is a work in progress, additional links are welcome!
