Community Wiki for Bitcoin
I noticed that on some popular stack exchange sites there are community wikis such as StackOverflow and Unix StackExchange.
Since we've graduated from beta, do we also get to start a community wiki?

I think we'll only graduate with the end of the election, and according to an answer on a related question a while back, it seems like they didn't like the results they got with it on Stackoverflow: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/829/5406

@Murch, I guess I was asking this because I saw a question like that in the Unix StackExchange https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me. And I thought we should have something like that for "Why my transaction isn't confirmation?" type questions.

I think you may be looking for this meta topic: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/697/5406? ;)
